# JavaScript pictureChange() and rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I've been searching for hours on the internet to solve my problem and I still can't find a solution. I'm new in JS, so I'm quite excited but still have some problems when writing the code. 
What I'd like to do is, onClick , change a picture with another while rotating it. I had the first part of my effect ( which only works once, then the image stop rotating), but I'd like to rotate it back again of 180 deg and change it with the first image. 
My idea was to do a menu with 3 bars, like google ones, which becomes a "X" when clicked, and vice versa. This is the first part of the script,

```
var img = document.querySelector('.navicon');

img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);

function onClick() {
var deg = 180 ;
var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';
this.setAttribute(
    'style', css  );

}
 function pictureChange()
{
document.getElementById("navicon").src="images/buttons/xbutton.png";

}
```

This is the CSS

```
.navicon:hover {
opacity:0.7;
}
.navicon {
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left:-75px;
position:relative;
display:block;
left:50%;
width: 45px;
height:45px;
left:500px; 
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

THis the HTML

```
<img src="images/buttons/navicon.png" class="navicon rotation"
    style="border=0;" id="navicon" onclick="pictureChange()">
```

I thought about adding a new class and call a function which only works with this new one, but it does not seem to work...
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally try to avoid setting css in javascript when I can. A better way is to use the javascript to add and remove classes, and let the css handle the actual transformation. In this case you can have some css like this:

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

and have the following line in your onClick function:

```
this.classList.toggleClass('rotate')
```

To change the image src back and forth, make variables (or an array) which hold the sources, and change them in the onClick function. No need to have onclick="pictureChange()" in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It works like a charm! I've used changeImage called by onClick="changeImage" to complete the animation! 
This is my final code
var newimage = "xbutton.png";

```
function changeImage() {
if ( newimage == "navicon.png" ) {
document.images["navicon"].src = "images/buttons/navicon.png";
document.images["navicon"].alt = "navicon";
newimage  = "xbutton.png";    }
else {
 document.images["navicon"].src = "images/buttons/xbutton.png";
document.images["navicon"].alt = "Earth";
newimage  = "navicon.png";   }
}
```

Thanks again for the advices